# MySQL - MySQL Workbench won't open (Windows 8)

Tags: mysql-workbench

I recently installed the web version of `MySQL` with `MySQL Workbench 6.9.3` but when i try to open it, it would crash right away (i tried opening it using the command line as well).

I have both `.NET` and `Visual Studio` installed so prerequisites is not the problem.
What is?

This is the error i get in the console:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write
 protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at wb.WBContext.read_state(WBContext* , basic_string<char\,std::char_traits<c
har>\,std::allocator<char> >* , basic_string<char\,std::char_traits<char>\,std::
allocator<char> >* , Int32* )
   at MySQL.Workbench.WbContext.read_state(String name, String domain, Int32 def
ault_value)
   at MySQL.GUI.Workbench.MainForm.LoadFormState()
   at MySQL.GUI.Workbench.MainForm.MainForm_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at MySQL.GUI.Workbench.MainForm.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr
wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: Looks like the states xml file got corrupted somehow. See in your roaming profile folder. There's a "MySQL Workbench" folder with various config and data files. One is the states xml file which is used to store part of the state of the application for restauration on next launch.

Comment: anything i could do then? I tried reinstalling MySQL, restarting my computer, nothing helped..

Comment: Ugh, sorry, just remove that file (or rename it). It will be recreated on next run.